# Check if database exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, exists

```
openDatabase(DB_SHORT_NAME, DB_VERSION, DB_DISPLAY_NAME, DB_MAX_SIZE)
```

in JavaScript opens database or creates the database if not exists in browser.

Is there any way I can able to check if database exists or not in browser?

Comment: I see an early negative mob..

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this. Better check if the database is empty or not.

Comment: Why do you need to check whether the db exists or not? You want to use the database, surely? If it exists, it's opened; if it doesn't exist, it's created. If you don't want to use the database, don't do anything. What am I missing here? (Edit your question, don't add a comment)

Comment: It's not a good idea to work with databses from javascript

Comment: How to check if the database is empty or not?

Comment: @richarbernal it is browser's local storage database, if you know anything else other than javascript then please specify.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript coined HTML5 is the only way to do this; you can use mobile libraries such as Phonegap or Titanium which will also render a Javascript library - however these are for mobile app development only; there mobile web versions are abysmal so don't consider converting it to mobile web and editing the fluid width values!

Do not forget that *not all* HTML5 browsers even support the database feature. It is limited. And so is support and it really is about finding out tutorials and trial and error. Those people that do; either blog it, or don't have a blog to post experiences (or so lazy and frustrated blogging about the headache is the last thing!).

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007917/check-if-db-exists-and-dropping-db-in-sqllite-ios

Some of many sites. (*shudders for the angry negative mob*)

You could try something like this:

```
// Uses jQuery
var db="mydb.db";
$.ajax({
    url:db,
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
    }
});
```

Here is the code for checking, whitout using jquery

```
    function dbExists(db)
    {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', db, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status!=404;
    }

var db="mydb.db";
dbExists(db);
```

Code is not really a live code; nor should I expect it to be - I know it is ugly.. but you get the idea surely. HTML5 local database and storage is poor. What is it you are trying to do?