# PhoneGap local storage sql delete sentence

Tags: javascript, database, cordova

I have great trouble with deleting a row in my local storage database with PhoneGap.

When i call the function deleterow() it fires of with an error saying "undefined".  Obviously the errorCB() function is called.  The row aint deleted.

What i do is i call my function through a HTML anchor tag like this.

```
<a onclick="deleterow('10')">Delete row</a>


function deleterow(id) {
    db.transaction(function(ctx) {
        ctx.executeSql('DELETE FROM <table> WHERE id=?', [id], successCB, errorCB); 
    });
}

OR    

function deleterow(id) {
    db.transaction(function(ctx) {
        ctx.executeSql('DELETE FROM <table> WHERE id='+id+'', [], successCB, errorCB);  
    });
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("Row deleted");
}
```

I have working example with:

```
INSERT
SELECT
UPDATE
CREATE
```

I find it very hard to believe that delete aint supported.

Am i right, or did i miss something?

I found a solution:

```
function delete(id) {
    db.transaction(function(ctx) {

    ctx.executeSql('DELETE FROM manyrecipes WHERE rowid=?', [id], delete_success, errorCB); 
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for making the edit in my title, i spell very bad :-)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little, what gives you an error "undefined"? Anything to trace?

Comment: Question is modified.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007917/check-if-db-exists-and-dropping-db-in-sqllite-ios

Comment: Actually...i think this might worked.. let me test! :-)

Comment: So far no success... updating question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the function syntax you are using for delete, try this:

```
function deleterow(id) {
db.transaction(function(ctx) {
    ctx.executeSql('DELETE FROM <table> WHERE id='+id+'', errorCB);  
    });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your suggestion looks excatly like mine in the original question.  I have 2 different ones.  What did u change?

Comment: the function syntax for the executeSql function call

Comment: Question closed and answer accepted.  I finally had the time to double check, thanks for the answer :-)